# Take Firebase Data Listeners at the right moment

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebaseui

I'm having a problem here.
I have a Firebase Database child called "users", inside it, I have other child called "teams", and I have to take the content inside "teams" and show them in a ListView with FirebaseAdapter.

The FirebaseAdapter is like this:

```
FirebaseListAdapter<String> firebaseListAdapter = new FirebaseListAdapter<String>(
            this,
            String.class,
            android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,
            //todo Conseguir exibir na lista, as equipes embedadas no usuário logado
            mRef.child("users").child(idUser).child("teams")


    )
```

As you can see, I wanna take the "teams" inside a specifc child, that I search using the "idUser".
This "idUser" is taken using a datasnapshot from the firebase, where I search for the id of the user logged on the app.
The datasnapshot code is below:

```
    user = mAuth.getCurrentUser().getEmail().toString();
    mRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
    Query query = mRef.child("usuarios").orderByChild("email").equalTo(user);
    query.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            for (DataSnapshot child : dataSnapshot.getChildren()){
                idUser = child.getKey().toString();
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });
```

My problem here is, the "idUser" is being called in the FirebaseListAdapter's code part before the query get being executed. So I get an error, because the idUser is empty. How can I solve this kinda problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this problem just moving the code of the firebaseadapter inside de listener.

Answer (score 0):

To solve this issue, move the declaration of `idUser` String inside the onDataChange() method, otherwise it will be always `null`.

```
String idUser = child.getKey().toString();
```

This is happening due the asynchronous behaviour of `onDataChange()` method, which is called before even you assign `.child(idUser)` to your `DatabaseReference`.

Moving the declaration inside the method and `using it` also there, solves your problem. Use also a log statement inside the method like this:

```
Log("TAG", idUser);
```

If you want to use the value of that String outside that method, please take a look at my answer from this post, [How To Get Async Value Outside onDataChange() Method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44152775/how-to-get-value-async-in-outside-method-ondatachange).

Hope it helps.